# Отправление писем с сайта с группировкой в цепочки, заголовки

Tags: email

Мне нужно отправить письма с сайта в цепочки, таким же образом как это делает Яндекс и другие крупные компании, что приходящие письма автоматически складываются в группу без дополнительных действий на стороне клиента.

Что то я не смог понять какой заголовок или заголовки за это отвечают.
Может быть кто то знает ?